# django-axes doesn't lock users after multiple failed login attempts

Tags: python, html, django, deployment, axis

- I'm using django axes and I'm running my tests, for now, in the admin login area, but for some reason, it's not blocking the user after consecutive failures. When I test it on my `localhost`, it works normally, but when I deploy it and do the tests with the site on the server, it doesn't block users. django is logging everything to the database as normal. I'll show my `settings.py` code below:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'axes',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    ... 
    'axes.middleware.AxesMiddleware',
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    # AxesStandaloneBackend should be the first backend in the AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS list.
    'axes.backends.AxesStandaloneBackend',
    # Django ModelBackend is the default authentication backend.
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
]

AXES_FAILURE_LIMIT = 3
import datetime as dt
delta = dt.timedelta(minutes=5)
AXES_COOLOFF_TIME = delta
AXES_RESET_ON_SUCCESS = True
AXES_ENABLE_ACCESS_FAILURE_LOG = True
AXES_LOCK_OUT_AT_FAILURE = True

USE_TZ = False
```

- I ran the commands `python manage.py check` and `python manage.py migrate`

OBS: I put the command `USE_TZ = False`, because I'm using mysql and from what I've read, it needs to be like this